# Core dumped in running Mesos cluster on docker

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, mesos

I have a docker image called ubuntu_mesos_spark. I installed zookeeper on it. I change “zoo.cfg” file like this:
This is “zoo.cfg” in node1(150.20.11.157)

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2187
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=150.20.11.157:2888:3888
server.3=150.20.11.137:2888:3888
```

This is “zoo.cfg” in node1(150.20.11.134)

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
clientPort=2187
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
server.1=150.20.11.157:2888:3888
server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.3=150.20.11.137:2888:3888
```

This is “zoo.cfg” in node1(150.20.11.137)

```
 tickTime=2000
 initLimit=10
 syncLimit=5
 clientPort=2187
 dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
 server.1=150.20.11.157:2888:3888
 server.2=150.20.11.134:2888:3888
 server.3=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
```

Also I made a “myid” file in “/var/lib/zookeeper” of each node. For example for “150.20.11.157” its ID is “1” in myid file.
I installed Mesos and Spark on the docker too. I have a Mesos cluster of these three nodes too. I defined IP address of slaves nodes on this file: “spark/conf/slaves”

```
150.20.11.134
150.20.11.137
```

I added these lines in “spark/conf/spark-env.sh”:

```
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=/home/spark/program_file/spark-2.3.2-bin- 
hadoop2.7.tgz
```

Moreover, I added these lines in my “~/.bashrc” file:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/home/spark"
PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7- 
src.zip:$PYTHO$
export PYSPARK_HOME=/usr/bin/python3.6
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3.6
export ZOO_LOG_DIR=/var/log/zookeeper
```

I  want to run master code in “150.20.11.157”.My docker-compose is :

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
  zookeeper:
  image: ubuntu_mesos_spark
  command: /zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/zkServer.sh start
  environment:
   ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
   ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2187
   ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
   ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
   ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
   ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 
   0.0.0.0:2888:3888;150.20.11.134:2888:3888;150.20.11.137:2888:3888
 network_mode: host
 expose:
  - 2187 
  - 2888
  - 3888
 ports:
  - 2187:2187
  - 2888:2888
  - 3888:3888

master:
image: ubuntu_mesos_spark
command: bash -c "sleep 20; /home/mesos-1.7.0/build/bin/mesos- 
master.sh --ip=150.20.11.157 --work_dir=/var/run/mesos"
restart: always
depends_on:
 - zookeeper
environment:
 - MESOS_HOSTNAME="150.20.11.157,150.20.11.134,150.20.11.137"
 - MESOS_QUORUM=1
 - MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos
expose:
 - 5050
 - 4040
 - 7077
 - 8080
ports:
  - 5050:5050
  - 4040:4040
  - 7077:7077
  - 8080:8080
```

Also, I run this compose file on slaves nodes :“150.20.11.134,150.20.11.137”:

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
  zookeeper:
  image: ubuntu_mesos_spark
  command: /zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/zkServer.sh start
  environment:
   ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
   ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2187
   ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
   ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
   ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
   ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 
   0.0.0.0:2888:3888;150.20.11.134:2888:3888;150.20.11.137:2888:3888
 network_mode: host
 expose:
  - 2187 
  - 2888
  - 3888
 ports:
  - 2187:2187
  - 2888:2888
  - 3888:3888

slave:
image: ubuntu_mesos_spark
command: bash -c "/home/mesos-1.7.0/build/bin/mesos-slave.sh -- 
master=150.20.11.157:5050 --work_dir=/var/run/mesos  
--systemd_enable_support=false"
restart: always
privileged: true
network_mode: host
depends_on:
- zookeeper
environment:
 - MESOS_HOSTNAME="150.20.11.157,150.20.11.134,150.20.11.137"
 - MESOS_MASTER=150.20.11.157
 - MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT=5mins #also in Dockerfile
 - MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos
 - MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos
 - MESOS_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
expose:
  - 5051
ports:
  - 5051:5051
```

First I run "sudo docker-compose up" on Master node. Then I run it on slaves nodes. But I get this error:

On Master node, the error is:

> Starting marzieh-compose_zookeeper_1 ... done
>
> Recreating marzieh-compose_master_1  ... done
>
> Attaching to marzieh-compose_zookeeper_1, marzieh-compose_master_1
>
> zookeeper_1  | ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
>
> zookeeper_1  | Using config: /zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
>
> zookeeper_1  | Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
>
> marzieh-compose_zookeeper_1 exited with code 0
>
> master_1     | I0123 11:46:59.585522     7 logging.cpp:201] INFO level logging started!
>
> master_1     | I0123 11:46:59.586066     7 main.cpp:242] Build: 2019-01-21 05:16:39 by 
>   master_1     | I0123 11:46:59.586097     7 main.cpp:243] Version: 1.7.0
>
> master_1     | F0123 11:46:59.587368     7 process.cpp:1115] Failed to initialize: Failed to bind on 150.20.11.157:5050: Cannot assign requested address
>
> master_1     | *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>
> master_1     |     @     0x7f505ce54b9c  google::LogMessage::Fail()
>
> master_1     |     @     0x7f505ce54ae0  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
>
> master_1     |     @     0x7f505ce544b2  google::LogMessage::Flush()
>
> master_1     |     @     0x7f505ce57770
>   google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
>
> master_1     |     @     0x7f505cd19ed1  process::initialize()
>
> master_1     |     @     0x55fb7b12981a  main
>
> master_1     |     @     0x7f504f0d0830  (unknown)
>
> master_1     |     @     0x55fb7b1288b9  _start
>
> master_1     | bash: line 1:     7 Aborted                 (core dumped) /home/mesos-1.7.0/build/bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=150.20.11.157 --work_dir=/var/run/mesos

Moreover when I run "sudo docker-compose up" on slave nodes. I got this error:

> slave_1      | F0123 11:40:06.878793     1 process.cpp:1115] Failed to initialize: Failed to bind on 0.0.0.0:5051: Address already in use
>
> slave_1      | *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d319b9c  google::LogMessage::Fail()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d319ae0  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d3194b2  google::LogMessage::Flush()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d31c770
>   google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d1deed1  process::initialize()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x55e99f661784  main
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee8f595830  (unknown)
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x55e99f65f139  _start
>
> slave_1      | *** Aborted at 1548243606 (unix time) try "date -d @1548243606" if you are using GNU date ***
>
> slave_1      | PC: @     0x7fee8f5ac196 (unknown)
>
> slave_1      | *** SIGSEGV (@0x0) received by PID 1 (TID 0x7fee9f9f38c0) from PID 0; stack trace: ***
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee8fee8390 (unknown)
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee8f5ac196 (unknown)
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d32055b google::DumpStackTraceAndExit()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d319b9c google::LogMessage::Fail()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d319ae0 google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d3194b2 google::LogMessage::Flush()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d31c770 google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee9d1deed1 process::initialize()
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x55e99f661784 main
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x7fee8f595830 (unknown)
>
> slave_1      |     @     0x55e99f65f139 _start
>
> slave_1      | I0123 11:41:07.818897     1 logging.cpp:201] INFO level logging started!
>
> slave_1      | I0123 11:41:07.819437     1 main.cpp:349] Build: 2019-01-21 05:16:39 by
>
> slave_1      | I0123 11:41:07.819470     1 main.cpp:350] Version: 1.7.0
>
> slave_1      | I0123 11:41:07.823354     1 resolver.cpp:69] Creating default secret resolver
>
> slave_1      | E0123 11:41:07.927773     1 main.cpp:483] EXIT with status 1: Failed to create a containerizer: Could not create 
>   DockerContainerizer: Failed to create docker: Failed to get docker version: Failed to execute 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --
>   version': exited with status 127

I searched a lot about that and I could not figure this out. Would you please guide me what the right way is to write docker compose for running Mesos and Spark cluster on docker?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I changed docker compose like this and Master and Slaves run without problem:

"docker-compose.yaml" in Master node is in the following:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
zookeeper:
 image: ubuntu_mesos_spark_python3.6_client
 command: /home/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/zkServer.sh start
 environment:
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
  ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2188
  ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
  ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
  ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
  ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 0.0.0.0:2888:3888;150.20.11.157:2888:3888
 network_mode: host
 expose:
  - 2188
  - 2888
  - 3888
 ports:
  - 2188:2188
  - 2888:2888
  - 3888:3888

master:
image: ubuntu_mesos_spark_python3.6_client
command: bash -c "sleep 30; /home/mesos-1.7.0/build/bin/mesos-master.sh 
--ip=150.20.10.136 --work_dir=/var/run/mesos --hostname=x.x.x.x"  ##hostname : 
IP of the master node
restart: always
network_mode: host
depends_on:
 - zookeeper
environment:
- MESOS_HOSTNAME="150.20.11.136"
- MESOS_QUORUM=1
- MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos
expose:
 - 5050
 - 4040
 - 7077
 - 8080
ports:
 - 5050:5050
 - 4040:4040
 - 7077:7077
 - 8080:8080
```

Also,"docker-compose.yaml" file in slave node is like this:

```
 version: '3.7'
 services:
  zookeeper:
   image: ubuntu_mesos_spark_python3.6_client
   command: /home/zookeeper-3.4.12/bin/zkServer.sh start
   environment:
     ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
     ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2188
     ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
     ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 10
     ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 5
     ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: 150.20.11.136:2888:3888;0.0.0.0:2888:3888
   network_mode: host
   expose:
   - 2188 
   - 2888
   - 3888
   ports:
   - 2188:2188
   - 2888:2888
   - 3888:3888

 slave:
 image: ubuntu_mesos_spark_python3.6_client
 command: bash -c "sleep 30; /home/mesos-1.7.0/build/bin/mesos-slave.sh 
 --master=150.20.11.136:5050 --work_dir=/var/run/mesos  
 --systemd_enable_support=false"
 restart: always
 privileged: true
 network_mode: host
 depends_on:
 - zookeeper
 environment:
 - MESOS_HOSTNAME="150.20.11.157"
 #- MESOS_MASTER=172.28.10.136
 #- MESOS_EXECUTOR_REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT=5mins #also in Dockerfile
 #- MESOS_CONTAINERIZERS=docker,mesos
 - MESOS_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mesos
 - MESOS_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
expose:
 - 5051
ports:
 - 5051:5051
```

Then I run "docker-compose up" in each node and they run without any problems.